# _Crypt_EncryptData() and _Crypt_DecryptData() confusion

Tags: encryption, autoit, 3des

I'm running into problems with `_Crypt_EncryptData()`. I want to encrypt data, store it, then read it back decrypted.

It seems  [`_Crypt_EncryptData()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Crypt_EncryptData.htm) and [`_Crypt_DecryptData()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Crypt_DecryptData.htm) are not symmetric; the former does an implicit hexadecimal encoding on the output value. But the latter does an implicit binary conversion on the input (so far so good), but then does an *implicit hexadecimal conversion* on its output! Hence within a single file:

```
$ciphertext=_Crypt_EncryptData($cleartext, $g_hKey, $CALG_3DES)
$cleartext=_HexToString(_Crypt_DecryptData($ciphertext, $g_hKey, $CALG_3DES))
```

(erk!) will give me back the original cleartext. I was unable to recover the cleartext from a file across invocations. The ciphertext was changing each time, e.g. with the string "This is a test", on subsequent executions I got:

```
 0x0B656F9BCC35B73A6EA9D08701E78713
 0xEBE1E744668C379CE74480C3A56303A2
 0x25F50D6B833B3CEF60FCFAF8AE673CF3
```

I would expect this if due to different initialization vectors, however looking at "Crypt.au3" I see no way to set or get the IV (I know DES3 is insecure - that's a different battle). Is it me or is it AutoIt?

Here is the full source of a script to reproduce the issue:

```
#include <StringConstants.au3>
#include <Crypt.au3>
#include <String.au3>

_Crypt_Startup() 
$inifile="C:\test_au_enc.ini"
$g_hKey = _Crypt_DeriveKey("s3cr3t.S4uce", $CALG_3DES)

; test previous invocation
$readback=IniRead($inifile, "main", "pass", "Failed")
if ("Failed"=$readback) Then
   MsgBox(0, "Enc Dec", "Failed to read ini file")
Else
   $dec=_HexToString(_Crypt_DecryptData($readback, $g_hKey, $CALG_3DES))
   MsgBox(0,"Enc Dec", "Read from previous: " & $dec)
   ; this fails to recover the cleartext
EndIf


$subj=InputBox("Enc Dec", "Please supply a string to encrypt", "This is a test");

; encrypt the string and write it to a file...
$enc=_Crypt_EncryptData($subj, $g_hKey, $CALG_3DES)
IniWrite($inifile, "main", "pass", $enc)

; now read back the value and decrypt
$readback=IniRead($inifile, "main", "pass", "Failed")
$dec=_HexToString(_Crypt_DecryptData($readback, $g_hKey, $CALG_3DES))
InputBox("Enc Dec", "Encrypted:" & $enc & @CRLF & "decrypted:" & $dec, $enc)
; here the decrypted text matches the cleartext
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [help file](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Crypt_EncryptData.htm); use of `_Crypt_DeriveKey()` is correct, but you are supposed to call `_Crypt_EncryptData()` and `_Crypt_DecryptData()` like this when using your own derived key:

```
$enc = _Crypt_EncryptData($subj, $g_hKey, $CALG_USERKEY)
$dec = _HexToString(_Crypt_DecryptData($readback, $g_hKey, $CALG_USERKEY))
```

Difference being `$CALG_USERKEY` for the `$iAlgID` parameter, which tells to treat the `$vCryptKey` parameter as a handle to a key instead of a password. This appears to work as intended.

Here is the full code:

```
#include <StringConstants.au3>
#include <Crypt.au3>
#include <String.au3>

_Crypt_Startup()
$inifile="C:\test_au_enc.ini"
$g_hKey = _Crypt_DeriveKey("s3cr3t.S4uce", $CALG_3DES)

; test previous invocation
$readback=IniRead($inifile, "main", "pass", "Failed")
if ("Failed"=$readback) Then
   MsgBox(0, "Enc Dec", "Failed to read ini file")
Else
   $dec=_HexToString(_Crypt_DecryptData($readback, $g_hKey, $CALG_USERKEY))
   MsgBox(0,"Enc Dec", "Read from previous: " & $dec)
   ; this fails to recover the cleartext
EndIf


$subj=InputBox("Enc Dec", "Please supply a string to encrypt", "This is a test");

; encrypt the string and write it to a file...
$enc=_Crypt_EncryptData($subj, $g_hKey, $CALG_USERKEY)
IniWrite($inifile, "main", "pass", $enc)

; now read back the value and decrypt
$readback=IniRead($inifile, "main", "pass", "Failed")
$dec=_HexToString(_Crypt_DecryptData($readback, $g_hKey, $CALG_USERKEY))
InputBox("Enc Dec", "Encrypted:" & $enc & @CRLF & "decrypted:" & $dec, $enc)
; here the decrypted text matches the cleartext
```

Comment: All you need to do is change `_Crypt_DecryptData($readback, $g_hKey, $CALG_3DES)` to `_Crypt_DecryptData($readback, $g_hKey, $CALG_USERKEY)`. $CALG_USERKEY is a constant in Crypt.au3 equal to zero. Just change the last parameter. And yes it worked for me. I will post the full code.

Comment: OMG I just read the source code of Crypt.au3. I expect your code will work (unable to test right now). But I'm gobsmacked that anyone thought this was a sensible way to write an API, and more so that they didn't bother to document it. Thank you for challenging me on this.